# Is it possible to use angularjs when writing a windows gadget?

Tags: angularjs, windows-desktop-gadgets

Everywhere I am looking, it is said that a gadget is basically html, javascript and css and that you can use your knowledge of the above to write a great gadget.

So, I am trying to do a simple gadget just to try some stuff (basically see that I can combine angularjs in my windows desktop gadget so I can do cool stuff later),

here is my html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    </head>

    <body style="width:350; height:350 ">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
        <div ng-app="" ng-init="name='Nim'"> 
            <p>Write something :) <input type="text" ng-model="name"></p>
            <p>You wrote: {{name}}</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I open this html via my browser (chrome) it works as expected, see the screen shot:

[image: screen shot of the web page (angular is doing its job!)]

but when it is in my windows gadget the angular part is not working. I can see my text, but the {{name}} part is shown as is and not updated, see the pic:

[image: my windows gadget (angular is not working)]

I have a feeling I am missing something silly...
I am not sure if I need gadget help or angularjs help or both so any help is very appreciated :)

Comment: Do people still use Windows sidebar "gadgets"?

Comment: They will when I am finished with mine ;), seriously, I never used them but I am asked to implement one...